# change dropdown on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check1" name="ohradio" checked>bike
</label>
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check2" name="ohradio">car
</label>
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check3" name="ohradio">cycle
</label>
<br /><br />
<select id="firstDropdown" class="">
    <optgroup >
      <option>bike 1</option>
      <option>bike 2</option>
      <option>bike 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select id="secondDropdown" class="myHide">
    <optgroup >
      <option>car 1</option>
      <option>car 2</option>
      <option>car 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select id="thirdDropdown" class="myHide">
    <optgroup >
      <option>cycle 1</option>
      <option>cycle 2</option>
      <option>cycle 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

code in `style.css` is below

```
.myHide{
    display: none;
}
.myVisible{
    display: block;
}
```

code in `custom.js` is below

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if(check2.checked){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if(check3.checked){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
    }
});
```

I want to change the drop-down list being displayed when a user selects a different radio button, for example when they click on the bike radio button the bike dropdown should be displayed and the other drop-downs should be hidden. However the above code isn't working. I am a beginner in jquery.

Comment: you should add an event listener which fire when any of the checkboxes is selected ,then hide or show accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put radio change event in your code. Just change your javascript script to

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    $("select").removeClass('myVisible myHide');
    if(check1.checked){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if(check2.checked){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if(check3.checked){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
    }
  });

});
```

See demo https://jsbin.com/lihusikoye/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Your output is correct but the problem is that 2nd and 3rd drop down are taking extra spacing above.

Comment: That's because of <br>, remove <br> then extra space will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    if($("#check2").attr("checked")=="checked") {
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if($("#check3").attr("checked")=="checked") {
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
    }
});
```

In some jquery versions `attr` mehtod dose not work. 
for that purpose you have to use `prop`

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the problem. OP wants to change the visible elements when a radio is changed. The `if` statements the OP currently has are fine

Comment: I wonder, its not working but in just 2 sec got  upvote..strange

Comment: i didn't add the $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){}); before.

Answer (score 0):

Should be;

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    if($('#check2').is(':checked'){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if($('#check3').is(':checked')){
        $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
        $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't change anything - the OPs `if` statements are correct

Answer (score 0):

you can change your radio to `

```
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check1" name="ohradio" data-show="firstDropdown"     checked>bike
</label>
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check2" name="ohradio" data-show="secondDropdown">car
</label>
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" id="check3" name="ohradio" data-show="thirdDropdown">cycle
</label>
```

and change your script to

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name='ohradio']", function () {
    $("select").fadeOut();
    $("#"+$(this).data("show")).fadeIn();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should be the complete truth:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    $("select").removeClass("myVisible");
    if($('#check1').is(':checked')){
      $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
      $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
      $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if($('#check2').is(':checked')){
      $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
      $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
      $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myHide');
    }
    if($('#check3').is(':checked')){
      $('#firstDropdown').addClass('myHide');
      $('#secondDropdown').addClass('myHide');
      $('#thirdDropdown').addClass('myVisible');
    }
  });
});
```

1. Implement change listener for `input[type='radio']`
2. Each time a radion button is clicked you have to remove the class `myVisible` from all select boxes.
3. Also set classes when `check1` is checked.

There is also a solution with shorter code, however if you are a beginner this is better to understand and for learning.

---

Short and more flexible:

Change the id's for select boxes like this:

```
<select id="sel_check1" class="myVisible">
  <optgroup >
    <option>bike 1</option>
    <option>bike 2</option>
    <option>bike 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="sel_check2" class="myHide">
  <optgroup >
    <option>car 1</option>
    <option>car 2</option>
    <option>car 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="sel_check3" class="myHide">
  <optgroup >
    <option>cycle 1</option>
    <option>cycle 2</option>
    <option>cycle 3</option>      
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Then you just need for js-code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
     $("select").removeClass("myVisible").addClass("myHide");            
     $("#sel_"+$(this).attr("id")).addClass("myVisible").removeClass("myHide");
  });
});
```